# css not working in IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I try this css on Chrome and FF and IE , the problem is not working on IE

```
.social {
    width: 100px; height: 100px;    
    display: block; text-align: center; 
    transform:rotateY(0deg);
    transition:transform .5s ease-out;
    transform-style:preserve-3d;
}
.social > div {
    width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #fff;
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;    
}
.social >.front {
    transform:translateZ(40px);    
}
.social >.back {
    transform:rotateY(-100deg) translateZ(40px);
}
.social:hover {
    transform: rotateY(100deg);
}
```

the html code:

```
<a class="social" href="search_resultsv.aspx"  onmouseover="document.getElementById('m_01').style.boxShadow = '0px 0px 5px #CCC'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('m_01').style.boxShadow = ''">
     <div class="front"><i class="fa fa-facebook"><img src="Content/menu/main/01_m.png" /></i></div>
     <div class="back"><i class="fa fa-facebook"><img id="m_01" class="img_shadow" src="Content/menu/main/01_b.png" /></i></div>
</a>
```

online demo on my website : [feee3.com](https://www.feee3.com)

Comment: its because IE 10,11 does not support `preserve-3d` property for `transfrom` and IE 8 and lower does not support `transfrom` at all

Comment: You should give more informations that "not working". What's the expecting behaviour, how is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**transform-style:preserve-3d is not supported IE currently!**

transform is still an experimental technology. 
Consider using vendor prefixes:

-ms- ,
-webkit- ,
-moz-

Comment: wont work, `-webkit-` prefix can help with some browsers, but not IE which dont support `preserve-3d`

Comment: Right! I didn't notice the 'preserve-3d' value

Comment: Thanks , i tested the css on windows edge and it worked perfectly